# Match everything until end markdown tag

Tags: regex, python-2.7, markdown

I want to match the contents of a markdown tag, but I have trouble when there are multiple equal tags in the string.

`string = "[caixa]text here[/caixa] more text [caixa] text [/caixa]"`

What I want is iterate over the tags (including the tag itself), which in this case would be:

`match1: "[caixa]text here[/caixa]"`

`match2: "[caixa] text [/caixa]"`

I've tried with negative lookahead, like `\[caixa\].+(?<!\[\/caixa\])\[\/caixa\]`, but it matches the whole text, from the initial opening tag to the last closing tag.

I am using re library in Python. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use: `r'\[caixa\].+?\[/caixa\]'` in `re.findall`

Comment: well that worked, tyvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any lookbehind or lookahead. If your tags are not nested then you can use lazy quantifier matching in this regex:

```
\[caixa\].+?\[/caixa\]
```

**RegEx Breakup**

```
\[caixa\]   # match starting tag "[caixa]"
.+?         # match one or more of any characters (lazy match)
\[/caixa\]  # match closing tag "[/caixa]"
```

**Code:**

```
>>> string = "[caixa]text here[/caixa] more text [caixa] text [/caixa]"
>>> print re.findall(r'\[caixa\].+?\[/caixa\]', string)
['[caixa]text here[/caixa]', '[caixa] text [/caixa]']
```